# Rails 6: Two actioncable channels for real time messaging, one doesnt refresh properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actioncable

I have two Actioncable channels setup(chatroom_channel and comment_channel). Comment channel isnt working.

The comment is being created and when I manually refresh the page the comment renders. However, the comment is supposed to render without manually pressing the refresh button from the browser.

This is the console output from the one that is working:

```
Started POST "/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-07-15 12:54:31 -0400
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"message"=>{"content"=>"hello"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
  Chef Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `current_chef'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  Message Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "chef_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "hello"], ["chef_id", 1], ["created_at", "2020-07-15 16:54:31.377225"], ["updated_at", "2020-07-15 16:54:31.377225"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
   (62.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:7:in `create'
  Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 247)
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to chatroom: {:message=>"<div class=\"message\">\n    <p>\n        <small><em>Created less than a minute ago</em></small>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n        <img alt=\"john\" class=\"rounded-circle\" src=\"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9e974c08914cda5ca2e7620c4fd3b6?s=50\" />\n        <strong>John </strong>\n        <span class=\"content\">\n            hello\n        </span>\n    </p>\n</div>", :chef=>"john"}
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 13.3ms | ActiveRecord: 63.1ms | Allocations: 5133)


ChatroomChannel transmitting {"message"=>"<div class=\"message\">\n    <p>\n        <small><em>Created less than a minute ago</em></small>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n        <img alt=\"john\" class=\"rounded-circle\" src=\"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9e974c08914cda5ca2e7620c4fd3b6?s=50\" />\n        <strong>John </strong>\... (via streamed from chatroom)
```

This is the console output from the one that is not working:

```
Started POST "/recipes/11/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-07-15 12:53:49 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"description"=>"test comment"}, "commit"=>"Submit Comment", "recipe_id"=>"11"}
  Chef Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "chefs".* FROM "chefs" WHERE "chefs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `current_chef'
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? ORDER BY "recipes"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Comment Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("description", "chef_id", "recipe_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["description", "test comment"], ["chef_id", 1], ["recipe_id", 11], ["created_at", "2020-07-15 16:53:49.203129"], ["updated_at", "2020-07-15 16:53:49.203129"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'
   (50.3ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (Duration: 1.7ms | Allocations: 1480)
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to comments: "<div class=\"row\">\n    <div class=\"col-md-2\">\n       <section class= \"chef_info center\">\n        <img alt=\"john\" class=\"rounded-circle\" src=\"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/1c9e974c08914cda5ca2e7620c4fd3b6?s=60\" />\n       </section> \n    </div>\n\n    <div class=\"comment col-md-8 card bg-light\">\n        <p>test comment</p>\n        <p class=\"quiet small\">Created: less than a minute ago by john</p>\n    </div>\n</div>"
Completed 200 OK in 121ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 52.0ms | Allocations: 23379)
```

The main difference is the last line `ChatroomChannel transmitting` while the other one doesnt have the equivelant. **It seems the CommentChannel isn't transmitting after it has been created?**

`app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb`:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_chef
    
    def connect
      self.current_chef = find_current_user
    end
    
    def disconnect
      
    end
    
    protected
    def find_current_user
      if current_chef = Chef.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:chef_id])
        current_chef
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`app/channels/comments_channel.rb`

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    stream_from "comments"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/comments_controller.rb`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    #ensure current chef is available
    before_action :require_user

    def create
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
        @comment = @recipe.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.chef = current_chef
        if @comment.save
            ActionCable.server.broadcast "comments", render(partial: 'comments/comment', object: @comment)
            #flash[:success] = "Comment was created successfully"
            #redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Comment was not created"
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        end
    end
    private
    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

`app/javascript/comments_channel.js`

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    return $("#messages").prepend(data);
  }
});
```

`app/views/recipes/show.html.erb`:

```
<%= render "shared/page_title", title: @recipe.name %>
<div class="col-md-8  offset-md-2 card card-body bg-light">
  <h4 class="center description"><strong>Steps: </strong></h4>
  <hr/>
  <%= simple_format(@recipe.description) %>
  <hr/>
  <% if @recipe.ingredients.any? %>
    <p>Ingredients: <%= render @recipe.ingredients %> </p>
  <% end %>
  <div class="ml-auto">
    <p class="center">
      <em>Created by:</em>
    </p>
    <p class="center">
      <%= link_to gravatar_for(@recipe.chef), chef_path(@recipe.chef) %>
    </p>
    <p class="center">
      <small><%= @recipe.chef.chefname.capitalize %></small>
      <div class="ml-auto"><%= time_ago_in_words(@recipe.created_at) %> ago</div>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-actions">
    <% if logged_in? && (current_chef == @recipe.chef || current_chef.admin?) %>
      <%= link_to "Edit this recipe", edit_recipe_path(@recipe), class: "btn btn-xs btn-warning" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete this recipe", recipe_path(@recipe), method: :delete,
       data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this recipe?"}, class: "btn -btn-xs btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to "Return to recipes listing", recipes_path, class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
  </div>
  
  <%# add likes glyph icons here %>


</div>


<%# add nested route for comment  %>
<% if logged_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <h3>Comments: </h3>
      <hr />
      <%= form_for([@recipe, @comment], remote: true, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
        <div class="row form-group">
          <%= f.label :Comment, :class => 'control-label col-md-2' %>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 8, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Enter comment here" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <%= f.submit "Submit Comment", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-xlarge" %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>


<%# if there are comments for this recipe, display them at the bottom %>
<% if @recipe.comments != 0 %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-8 offset-md-2"> 
      <h3>Prior Comments: </h3>
      <div id="messages">
        <%= render partial: 'comments/comments', object: @comments %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <h3> No comments yet! </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

`gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.1'

# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

#add pagination to the site
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.7'
#gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 1.0'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap4'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'redis'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```